# R MatchIt() with ratio>1 and caliper=0.1

Tags: r, matching

R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
MatchIt version 2.4-21 (2013-06-27)

I am using the `MatchIt()` package in R to 2:1 propensity score match my `control` and `treatment` groups. However, when I apply the `caliper` argument to the function, it allows 1:1 matches to occur, such that my final matched cohorts are not 2:1 matched. For example, if I start with 80 treatment and 200 control units, my matched cohort may then be 62 treatment and 94 control units (rather than 124 control units).

Is there a way to force the `ratio` argument to override the `caliper` argument, thereby only retaining treatment units for which there are at least 2 matched control units? (ie. I would like to discard treatment units that have only 0 or 1 matched control units within the specified caliper).

My function call is below:

```
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ x1 + x2, data=data, method = "nearest", discard = "both", 
caliper = 0.1, ratio = 2)
```